# Using Gson to parse subclasses with different fields

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am parsing data that has a response template that resembles this:

```
{
  response: {
    data: {}
  }
  meta: {
    errors: []
    success: 1
  }
}
```

For each specific response, the "data" field is populated with dynamic fields, but all other keys (meta, etc.) remain the same.  For example:

ClassA

```
data: {
  foo: ""
}
```

ClassB

```
data: {
  bar: 3
}
```

How can I model my classes and use Gson to represent this data?  Currently I've got:

```
public class BaseResponse {
  @SerializedName("meta") public Meta meta;

  public class Meta {
    @SerializedName("errors") public ArrayList<Error> errors;
    @SerializedName("success") public int success;
  }
}

public class ClassA extends BaseResponse {
  @SerializedName("foo") public String foo;
}

public class ClassB extends BaseResponse {
  @SerializedName("bar") public int bar;
}
```

Unfortunately, the foo and bar fields return null values when parsing, using, e.g.:

```
Gson.fromJson(jsonString, ClassA.class);
```

I believe this is due to the "foo" and "bar" fields being inner references.

Comment: I don't know much about gson but when you said that the parsing return null, what was the value of jsonString  when you called `Gson.fromJson(jsonString, ClassA.class);` ?

Comment: For a ClassA response it would look like {
  response: {
    data: {foo: "Foo!"}
  }
  meta: {
    errors: []
    success: 1
  }
}

Comment: For a ClassB response it would look like { response: { data: {bar: 350} } meta: { errors: [] success: 1 } }

Comment: Have you created those json yourself or was it by `gson.toJson(a,ClassA.class)` or something like that?

Comment: Because I think your json annotation doesn't represent the json that you provided. So you will need to modify your class. I think that you will probably need in your `BaseResponse` a `private ClassA a` or something like that. I'll try giving you a better anwser later tonigth.

Comment: I am consuming the json from an API, it's not generated internally.

Comment: Inner classes are fine. I don't see a mapping to "data" anywhere.

Answer (score 7):

As I understand the problem, custom processing is necessary to provide the desired polymorphic deserialization, where the decision for which type to use is based on the presence of specific JSON element names.  (Since the JSON doesn't contain type information, switching to another serialization API, like [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org), wouldn't provide for a simpler solution.)

The following demonstrates the approach I'd likely take.

```
package com.stackoverflow.q15578106;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

public class Foo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    /*
      {
        "response": {"data": {"foo": "FOO"}},
        "meta": {"errors": [], "success": 1}
      }
     */
    String input1 = "{\"response\": {\"data\": {\"foo\": \"FOO\"}},\"meta\": {\"errors\": [], \"success\": 1}}"; 

    /*
      {
        "response": {"data": {"bar": 42}},
        "meta": {"errors": [], "success": 1}
      }
     */
    String input2 = "{\"response\": {\"data\": {\"bar\": 42}},\"meta\": {\"errors\": [], \"success\": 1}}";

    processInput(input1);
    // {"response":{"data":{"foo":"FOO"}},"meta":{"errors":[],"success":1}}

    processInput(input2);
    // {"response":{"data":{"bar":42}},"meta":{"errors":[],"success":1}}
  }

  static void processInput(String jsonInput)
  {
    DataDeserializer dataDeserializer = new DataDeserializer();
    dataDeserializer.registerDataType("foo", A.class);
    dataDeserializer.registerDataType("bar", B.class);

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Data.class, dataDeserializer).create();

    BaseResponse response = gson.fromJson(jsonInput, BaseResponse.class);
    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(response)); 
  }
}

class DataDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Data>
{
  Map<String, Class<? extends Data>> dataTypeRegistry = new HashMap<String, Class<? extends Data>>();

  void registerDataType(String jsonElementName, Class<? extends Data> javaType)
  {
    dataTypeRegistry.put(jsonElementName, javaType);
  }

  @Override
  public Data deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException
  {
    JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
    for (String elementName : dataTypeRegistry.keySet())
    {
      if (jsonObject.has(elementName))
      {
        Class<? extends Data> dataType = dataTypeRegistry.get(elementName);
        return context.deserialize(jsonObject, dataType);
      }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Oops");
  }
}

class BaseResponse
{
  Response response;
  Meta meta;
}

class Meta
{
  List<String> errors;
  int success;
}

class Response
{
  Data data;
}

class Data
{

}

class A extends Data
{
  String foo;
}

class B extends Data
{
  int bar;
}
```